# GitHub status checks with reusable workflows

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to set up a GitHub Actions workflow for PR checking that calls into a reusable workflow, and I'd want this PR Check workflow to be treated as a Status Check for the Pull Request conditions. The problem is that GitHub doesn't let me select the root action as the status check but only shows me the full reusable workflows.

```
- ./.github/workflows
    - PR.yml
    - _build_and_test.yml
```

```yaml
# PR.yml
on:
    pull_request:
jobs:
    build_test:
        strategy:
            matrix:
                version: [1, 2]
        uses: ./.github/workflows/_build_and_test.yml
        with:
            param: ${{ matrix.version }}
```